# Google maps addition

Tags: qgis

I recently added a Google satellite map in my new project and it's simply not showing, what could be the problem?[image]

Comment: There could be many reasons. You need to give more details. For example: How did you add it? What URL do you use? What is your Network setup (proxy or no proxy)? And so on.

Comment: Solved now I have added a comment below

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in some other data and zooming to it.

It sometimes does not show because you are too zoomed out.

Comment: Thankyou  Heikki Vesanto  I zoomed out and it is now showing also I had to be connected to the internet for the map to load,I downloaded the  contributed pack previously so I thought it would work without being connected